# How to get a default index or index with number in python dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe which has the 10 unique countries within 100 rows. Now by applying value_counts(), I am trying to get the frequency of occurance of each country. I need this to be in a dataframe.

```
This is the output of value_counts:
South Africa    166
USA             164
Spain           134
Sweeden         119
France          115
Russia           97
India            95
UK               95
Ukraine           9
Ireland           5
Name: Country, dtype: int64
```

I need this to be made into a new dataframe, but it should have index values as 0,1,2....
I tried below
country=pd.DataFrame(so_survey_df['Country'].value_counts())

but it gave a dataframe with Country name as index.

Comment: `so_survey_df['Country'].value_counts().reset_index(name='Count')`.

Comment: Thanks but I am looking for a better line of code through I can name both my columns as country and count. The above code gives me dataframe with columns index and count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
pd.Series({val:k for k,val in df['country'].value_counts().iteritems()})
```

Output:

```
166    South Africa
164             USA
134           Spain
119         Sweeden
115          France
97           Russia
95               UK
9           Ukraine
5           Ireland
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

So basically you need to count the values, reset the index and change the columns name, thus a one line code can be:

```
country = so_survey_df['Country'].value_counts().reset_index(name='Count').rename(columns={'index':'Country'})
```